# How to transform mechanical work into electrical energy without using piezoelectricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, pressure, energy-conservation, work, piezoelectric

can someone help me with the following issue. I need a method for transforming mechanical work into electrical energy without using piezoelectricity. I have such kind of mechanical forces (like on the picture in the link) and I want to transform this mechanical force into electrical energy.

[mechanical energy](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/SchemaPiezo.gif)

Comment: Look at [hydroelectricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroelectricity) or [wind power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_power).

Comment: use set's of gear's and pullys  to run a generator

Comment: Can you define the problem better?  What kind of force are you talking about and what is the size/scale of the possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the hint from Rodrigo more specific, you could take a look at high impedance electromagnetic headphones. It is basically a coil that magnetizes a piece of iron when a current is run through the wires. This magnet will then attract a metal sheet or a diaphragm just like the one in your picture.

[image]

Now you could think about reversing the process, and directly connect the diaphragm to a permanent magnet inside the coil. Now a movement will create a current in your coil wire.

Comment: Hey Matthias, vielen vielen Dank, genau das brauche ich für mein Projekt :)

Comment: Bitte ;)  und viel Erfolg!

Comment: Danke, dir auch alles Gute!

Comment: If this concept works for your solution, then I suggest you look at linear motors.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_alternator like this flashlight http://discovercircuits.com/H-Corner/shake-chgr.htm

Comment: Also you can run a linear motor backwards to turn it into a generator.  More examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motor

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an electrical engineer, but I think this can help:

"Although  the  various  conversion  devices 
operate  on  similar  principles,  their  structures  depend  on  their  function. Devices  for 
measurement  and  control  are  frequently  referred  to  as  transducers; they  generally 
operate  under  linear  input-output  conditions  and  with  relatively  small  signals.  The 
many examples  include  microphones,  pickups,  sensors,  and  loudspeakers.  A  second 
category  of  devices  encompasses force-producing  devices and  includes  solenoids, 
relays,  and  electromagnets.  A  third  category  includes  continuous  energy-conversion 
equipment such  as  motors  and  generators."

Source: FITZGERALD, A. E. Electric Machinery, 6 ed. McGraw Hill

I believe the best way you can convert mechanical work into electrical energy is through an electric generator. An electric generator works through electromagnetic inductance which is the property of a conductor by which a change in current in the conductor "induces" (creates) a voltage in both the conductor itself and in any nearby conductors.

There are many options of electric generators, but I believe the more common are the dynamo, which produces direct current through the use of a commuter, and the alternator, which produces alternating current. In general, the use of a commuter makes the dynamo more expensive and therefore the alternator is more common in the industry due to efficiency, reliability and cost reasons, since it's cheaper to transform alternating current into direct current through power rectification devices.

Here is a reasonable source for you to know more:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator

I hope it helps!